# Does there exist a lattice with a unique coatom, but whose unique coatom is not the second-from-top element?

Tags: lattice-orders

Does there exist a (necessarily infinite) lattice $L$ which has a unique coatom, but such that the unique coatom is not the second-from-top element? By second-from-top, I mean, if the top element was deleted from the lattice, the second-from-top would then be the new top element in the resulting partial order.

Comment: Start with the real interval $[0,1]$ under the usual order, and add a new element $c$ that is incomparable with any real number $x\in (0,1)$, but which is required to satisfy $0<c<1$. The element $c$ will be a unique coatom, but not be second-from-top.

Comment: @KeithKearnes You should probably put that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with the real interval $[0,1]$ under the usual order, and add a new element $c$ that is incomparable with any real number $x\in (0,1)$, but which is required to satisfy $0<c<1$. The element $c$ will be a unique coatom, but not be second-from-top.

Comment: In a precise sense, this strategy is unavoidable. Suppose $L$ is a bounded lattice with top $1$, bottom $0$, and unique coatom $c$, but $c$ is not "second-from-the-top." Then we can find $a_1<1$ which is not below $c$. Since $a_1$ is not a coatom, we can find $a_2\in (a_1,1)$ and iteratively find $a_{n+1}\in (a_n,1)$. The subset $X=\{a_1\wedge c,1,c,a_1,a_2,...\}$ is a sublattice of $L$; it's basically the $1,2,1$ lattice with one of the intermediate elements replaced with an $\omega$-chain. (cont'd)

Comment: So any example of such a lattice contains a copy of $X$, and this $X$ is itself such a lattice. (The difference between this $X$ and the lattice in the above answer is purely superficial.)